# Alternative to DOM input fields using "native" P5js objects

Tags: javascript, dom, p5.js

While P5 supports integration of DOM elements, for the sketch I'm working on I would prefer to keep all graphic elements including the form input fields in the P5 canvas. Mainly to avoid maintaining parallel style methods in P5 and CSS and other reasons having to do with "scene" management in the game.

Can anyone recommend an approach replicate the DOM "createInput" function for capturing text input and pushing it to an array?

I was thinking of trying to capture the code using the global `keyTyped` function,

```
function keyTyped() {
  optionA += key;
}
```

But this seems a bit hackish because 
a) I'd rather have the user be able to and then "submit" the text entry with a separate button element or object. 
and 
b) I'm not sure how best to associate this global keyTyped function with a specific P5 object.

Any ideas?